# Como passar parametros para execute em uma thread Delphi

Tags: delphi, thread

estou com dificuldade em atribuir um valor de uma variável dentro do Execute de uma Thread.

preciso atribuir um valor para a variável **Name** através da **FName** que está dentro do execute de uma thread.

segue exemplo que estou tentando fazer.

```
program Project2;

uses
  System.SysUtils, Classes;

type
  TTest = class(TThread)
  private
    var FName: string;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    constructor Create(const CreateSuspended: boolean; out AName: string);
  end;


{ TTest }
constructor TTest.Create(const CreateSuspended: boolean; out AName: string);
begin
  AName:= 'Test2';
  FName:= AName;
  inherited Create(CreateSuspended);
end;

procedure TTest.Execute;
begin
  FName:= 'Teste3';
end;


var
  Name: string;
  Test: TTest;
begin

  Name:= 'Teste1';
  WriteLn(Name);

  Test:= TTest.Create(False, Name);
  WriteLn(Name);

  ReadLn;
end.
```

Comment: Porque editou a pergunta dessa forma ?

Answer (score 1):

Em primeiro lugar, eu não vejo vínculos entre `FName` e `Name`.
Para isso é necessário você implementar este trecho na sua classe:

```
public
  property Name: string read FName write FName;
```

Com isso você estará dizendo para o compilador, que a Property `Name`, vai ser lida e escrita como `FName`

Nesse caso como a implementação é toda feita na mesma unit, o seu código principal vai ser capas de acessar a variável `FName` diretamente, mas em casos mais complexos onde o código é orientado a objeto, é necessário criar essa property em `public`.

A segunda questão, é que neste seu exemplo, o Retorno vai ser `Teste1` e `Teste2`, mas acredito que você esteja esperando um `Teste3` no lugar do `Teste2`, certo ?

Se esse for o caso, o que acontece é o seguinte:

```
1) Você joga no console o valor `Teste1`
2) Você Cria a Thread
3) O método `create` da Thread alimenta o `FName` com `Teste2`
4) Você joga no console o valor de `FName`
5) A Thread altera o valor de `FName` para `Teste3`
```

Exato!, o seu `WriteLn(Name);` esta vindo antes do `Execute` da sua Thread. 
Lembre-se, você está trabalhando com processos paralelos.

Segue o código ajustado para melhores esclarecimentos:

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}


uses
  System.SysUtils, Classes;

type
  TTest = class(TThread)
  private
    FName: string;

  protected
    procedure Execute; override;

  public
    property Name: string read FName write FName;

    constructor Create(const CreateSuspended: boolean);
  end;

var
  Test: TTest;
  { TTest }



constructor TTest.Create(const CreateSuspended: boolean);
begin
  FName := 'Test2';
  inherited Create(CreateSuspended);
end;



procedure TTest.Execute;
begin
  inherited;
  FName := 'Teste3';
end;


var
  Name: String;
begin

  Name := 'Teste1';
  WriteLn(Name);

  Test := TTest.Create(False);
  //Sleep(1000); // Este sleep vai fazer com que o Execute da thread consiga alterar o valor antes do WriteLn.

  Name := Test.Name;
  WriteLn(Name);

  ReadLn;

end.
```

Comment: @DaniloAlves, baseado no seu comentário, volto a frisar. Sua variável `Name` não tem ligação nenhuma com o `FName`.
No create da sua thread o `FName` recebe `Name`, mas em momento algum o `Name` que é no tipo `out`, recebe um valor de volta. Ou seja, você não faz nada com a variável `Name`. Se você quiser manter o código do jeito que está ( confuso ), é só você fazer o `Name := Test.FName` antes de exibi-lo no log do console.